# Dialog CSS Style SAP UI5

Tags: css, xml, dialog, sapui5

I have a simple SAP UI5 application, where the user open an add dialog pop-up,
I want to change the style of the dialog, the xml of the dialog is something like this:

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core ="sap.ui.core" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml>"
   <Dialog title="Add" class="sapUiPopupWithPadding">
     <Input type="Text"/>
     <buttons class="buttonsStyle">
       <Button text="Save"/>
       <Button text="Cancel"/>
     </buttons>
   </Dialog>
 </core:FragmentDefinition>
```

The CSS:

```
.buttonsStyle {
 background-color: #d8d8d8 !important;
}
```

I always get the same result as the picture no matter how I change the CSS, I want to change the color and size of the dialog title (Add) and the background color and font color of the buttons but I get no result by trying and searching.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For buttons you should favor the type attribute over custom CSS ;)

See the API reference & samples for ButtonType

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Button%23controlProperties
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ButtonType
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.Button/sample/sap.m.sample.Button

For the Dialog, you can use the customHeader aggregation and use some customizable component in place of the title.

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Dialog%23aggregations